# How to transform the test data after applying target encoding with smoothing?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-science

If we apply Leave One Encoding or Target Encoding with smoothing to training data and calculate smoothed scores, how can and should we transform the test data? Is it good to use smoothing on training only and transform the test data with the normal target encoded values? Or the smoothed scores that are being calculated for training should be used for testing set? Like what a friend of mine was saying to replace categorical variables in test set with Target encoded scores calculated for each category and not with smoothed values as they are only calculated for over-fitting. But I think if we are doing something to training, same things should be happened to test set. Please clear my doubt.